# Have a list of objects as a foreign key

Tags: entity-framework

If I have two classes:

```
 public class Event
    {
        public int EventId { get; set; }
        public string EventName { get; set; }

    }
```

and

```
public class Dog
    {
        public int DogId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

I would like for my `event`-class to be able to have a list of `dog` attached to it. 
How can I make my event-class understand that I want it to be able to contain a list of dogs?
I am using entity framework. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using Code-First:

```
public class Event
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
}

public class Dog
{
    public int DogId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Event")]
    public int EventID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
}
```