# Entity framework many-to-many relationship

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Ok, I'm trying to figure out how to setup my DB properly.

I have two classes:

```
public class Event
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Dog
{
    public int DogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

An event must be able to contain a collection of dogs.
Every dog must be able to be part in any event.
I'm guessing this is what they call a many-to-many relationship, but I do not now how to set it up with keys etc. I hope I'm clear enough with what I'm hoping to achieve.

I asked a similar question yesterday but I was then not clear over what I needed:
[Have a list of objects as a foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614828/have-a-list-of-objects-as-a-foreign-key).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is a N:N relationship. Assuming Code First, change your entities:

```
public class Event
{
    public Event()
    {
       Dogs = new HashSet<Dog>();
    }
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
}

public class Dog
{
    public Dog()
    {
       Events = new HashSet<Event>();
    }
    public int DogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

And your `OnModelCreating`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<Dog>()
    .HasMany(d => d.Events)
    .WithMany(e => e.Dogs)
    .Map(m =>
    {
       m.MapLeftKey("DogId");
       m.MapRightKey("EventId");
       m.ToTable("DogEvent");
    });
}
```

This should then create a junction table `DogEvent` with just the two foreign keys, `DogId` and `EventId`

Comment: Thank you!
I have no prior knowledge to the OnModelCreating-method. I´ll look into this.

Answer (score 2):

You should just need an `ICollection<T>` property on each class:

```
public class Event
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
}

public class Dog
{
    public int DogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

EF should be able to handle a many-to-many relationship without you explicitly defining the mapping, but if you want to set up the junction table yourself, you can do that by overriding the `OnModelCreating` method (as explained in other answers).

Answer (score 2):

It would still be quite similar to your question yesterday.  See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/234606/Creating-a-Many-To-Many-Mapping-Using-Code-First for a good blog post on the subject.

```
public class Event
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }

    public Event()
    {
        Dogs = new HashSet<Dog>();
    }

}

public class Dog
{
    public int DogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }

    public Dog()
    {
        Events = new HashSet<Dog>();
    }
}
```

The idea behind the code above (and from your previous question) is A dog can have a "collection" of events it is associated with, and events can have a collection of dogs that are associated to it.

Comment: Thank you! 
I will have a look at the link as well!