# 2 foreign keys in one table using entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have three classes

```
Event, Dog, Result
```

Each dog can participate in many events and for each event he will get a score related to this specifik event.
Thus must mean that my result-class must contain 2 foreign keys. 1 that specifies the event and 1 that specifies the dog. I am very confused about how to set this up. I´ve been getting som help with this earlier and I hope someonen can help me again:

Here are my classes now:

public class Dog
    {

```
    public int DogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
    public string DogImage { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Event")]
    public int EventID { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Result> Results { get; set; }

    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
}

public class Event
    {
        public int EventId { get; set; }
        public string EventName { get; set; }
        public string EventLocation { get; set; }
        public string EventType { get; set; }
        public string EventDate { get; set; } 

        public virtual ICollection<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
    }

 public class Result
    {
        public int ResultId { get; set; }
        public int Track { get; set; }
        public int Obedience { get; set; }
        public int Protection { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Dog")]
        public int DogId { get; set; }

        public virtual Dog Dog { get; set; }
    }
```

Help appreciated, thanks!

EDIT:

Ok, this is how it looks now. I should tellyou that when i tried to do a mgration with these updates I received an error ending with: `may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.`

I added this method in my dbcontext and it took care of that provblem(I Think...)

```
public class EfdbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Result> Results { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
    .HasRequired(c => c.Results)
    .WithMany()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

Now when I try to migrate I get this error:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Events_dbo.Results_Results_ResultId". The conflict occurred in database "CloudDog.EFDB.EfdbContext", table "dbo.Results", column 'ResultId'.
>   And this is how my classes look now:

```
public class Event
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public string EventLocation { get; set; }
    public string EventType { get; set; } //Dropdown med tävlingar
    public string EventDate { get; set; } //Picker

    public virtual ICollection<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Result> Results { get; set; }
}

public class Dog
{
    public int DogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
    public string DogImage { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Event")]
    public int EventId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Merit> Merits { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Result> Results { get; set; }

    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
}

 public class Result
{
    public int ResultId { get; set; }
    public int Track { get; set; }
    public int Obedience { get; set; }
    public int Protection { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Dog")]
    public int DogId { get; set; }
    public virtual Dog Dog { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Event")]
    public int EventId { get; set; }      
    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your fluent API statement is wrong: A Result has both a Required Dog and a required Event. Both an Event and a Dog have many Results.

Comment: Thank you, do you mind showing me the right way to do it, I have never before created a fluent api. I found the above example here at the forum.

Comment: I have rather limited editing capabilities here, hence my rather sober answer. Gert explained it much better and he is online. I could edit his answer to include the fluent API call, but propably he will follow up himself soon. Basically you need `Entity<Event>().HasMany(ev=>ev.Results).WithRequired(res=>res.Event).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);`

Answer (score 2):

In your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637988/entity-framework-many-to-many-relationship) you didn't tell the whole story. In itself the solution was correct. When there is *nothing but* a many-to-many association between two classes then EF can model this by a junction table that remains invisible in the class model.

But now you add more information to this junction table. This means that the table must be represented as a class in the class model, otherwise you'll never be able to access this information. Now your model should look like this (reduced to the essentials):

```
public class Dog
{
    public int DogId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Result> Results { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Result> Results { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public int ResultId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Dog")]
    public int DogId { get; set; }
    public virtual Dog Dog { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Event")]
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public virtual Dog Event { get; set; }
}
```

Logically, there's still a many-to-many association between `Dog` and `Event`, but *technically* it is implemented as a 1-n-1 association. So by adding information you sacrifice the shortcut access from `Dog`s to `Event`s and back. This is very common though. I don't often see pure many-to-many associations. Sooner or later people start storing information *about* the association.

Now if you want to fetch a `Dog`'s `Event`s, you'll have to write a somewhat more complicated query:

```
from d in Dogs
from r in d.Results
select r.Event
```

Comment: `Event` can't have this collection `Dogs` anymore. The migration issue is a different issue, related to data in your table. You better ask a new question for that, showing which data are involved. We like to stay on-topic at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you again. But i do not understand. If event can no longer have a collection of dog s attached to it, how can I then see what dogs are related to a spcifik event? 

I have also now deleted the database in order to be able to create a new one with the correct setting.

Comment: @GertArnold I disagree that the fluent API issue would belong to a new question. The Exception about the multiple cascading delete paths follows anytime an explicit many to many relation is implemented (when on SQL Server). So a full answer to the uninitiated should include the fluent API code as well.

Comment: So i have cleared my DB now. And I have changed the API and the entitys. When now try to create an event for my db i get this error:
Foreign key 'FK_dbo.Dogs_dbo.Events_EventID' references invalid table 'dbo.Events'.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

MEaning that I cant create a new db

Comment: @user2915962 I think you should make a new question with all your code now. Mind: Dogs do not have Events any more, nor do Events have Dogs. Read Gert's answer carefully.

Comment: Thank you, i try to understand by reading your answers but I think its a bit over my head understanfing how to solve it. Created new question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26698029/entity-framwork-many-to-many-relationship

Comment: Sorry, had to go, couldn't respond for a while. @Dabblernl the fluent API issue is related,  I agree, but the OP solved that well.

Answer (score 1):

The ‘Result‘ class is the junction table that embodies the many to many relation between dogs and events. So the Dogs property on Event and the Events property on Dog should be An ICollection of Result. The Result class is really a DogInEvent class.