# Entity Framework errors when trying to create many-to-many relationship

Tags: entity-framework

This is a break-out question from:
[2 foreign keys in one table using entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692270/2-foreign-keys-in-one-table-using-entity-framework/26694838?noredirect=1#comment41990133_26694838)

I'm trying to sort out my relationships in these there tables:

```
public class Event
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public string EventLocation { get; set; }
    public string EventType { get; set; }
    public string EventDate { get; set; } 

    public virtual ICollection<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Result> Results { get; set; }
}

public class Dog
{
    public int DogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
    public string DogImage { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Event")]
    public int EventId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Merit> Merits { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Result> Results { get; set; }

    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public int ResultId { get; set; }
    public int Track { get; set; }
    public int Obedience { get; set; }
    public int Protection { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Dog")]
    public int DogId { get; set; }
    public virtual Dog Dog { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Event")]
    public int EventId { get; set; }      
    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
```

}

From what I understand from the original question I do not need my Event-class to be able to hold a collection of dogs. This goes over my head? I do not understand how to set this up properly in order for Each dog to participate in many events and for each event he will get a score related to this specific event.

I also have this method in my `dbContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
    .HasRequired(c => c.Results)
    .WithMany()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

The error I get now while trying to create an event is this:

> Foreign key 'FK_dbo.Dogs_dbo.Events_EventID' references invalid table 'dbo.Events'.
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Thank you!

EDIT:

Earlier I used this code to add dogs to an event:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DogsInEvent(DogsInEventVm model)
        {
            var choosenEvent = _ef.SingleEvent(model.ChoosenEvent.EventId);
            choosenEvent.Dogs =  new Collection<Dog>();
            choosenEvent.Dogs = model.Dogs.Where(o => o.Checked).ToList();
            _ef.AddDogsToEvent(choosenEvent);

            return RedirectToAction("AllEvents");
        }
```

Ofcourse this is not possible any longer since my event does not hold a list of dogs anymore. 
Am I really down the right path here? How can I possibly establish a relationship between a list of dogs and an event?

Comment: Take out Event.Dogs. Take out Dog.Event. Change the fluent Api call to the one I wrote in my comment to your previous question.

Comment: Thank you! Now i managed to add an event without prtoblems. I´ll try around with this!

Comment: Would you please have a look at my edit if you have the time. Im not feeling to sure about his.

Comment: The way to establish the relationship between `Dog` and `Event` is now to create `Result` objects having the correct references of foreign key values. So any method that establishes such an association should also provide/store the details of the result. These should be present in the view model.

Comment: Your edit is a new question again.  please answer the unedited question by supplying the code that made it work.

Comment: Thank you both. Ill try to create som code that establishes a connection between dog and event by using the resukt-class.