# Entity framework relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have these three entities:

```
public class Dog
{
    public int DogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
    public string DogImage { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Result> Results { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public string EventLocation { get; set; }
    public string EventType { get; set; } 
    public string EventDate { get; set; } 

    public virtual ICollection<Result> Results { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public int ResultId { get; set; }
    public int Track { get; set; }
    public int Obedience { get; set; }
    public int Protection { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Dog")]
    public int DogId { get; set; }
    public virtual Dog Dog { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Event")]
    public int EventId { get; set; }      
    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
}
```

I´ve been getting help from here before in order to set it up like this.
[Entity Framework errors when trying to create many-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26698029/entity-framework-errors-when-trying-to-create-many-to-many-relationship)

So the way it is now I guess the `result` is the "glue" that ties these classes together containing foreign keys to the two other tables.

**What I  have been trying to achieve for days now is to:**

1. Create an event.
2. Add dogs to the event.
3. Add results to the dogs participating in the choosenEvent.

Lets say I create an event like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateEvent(Event newEvent)
{
    newEvent.EventDate = newEvent.EventDate.ToString();
    _ef.AddEvent(newEvent);

    return View();
}
```

Now I guess the next step would be to add a list of dogs to this event and in order to do that I need to somehow use my result-class since that's the "glue"-class. Please let me know if I'm even on the right track here.

Comment: wouldnt it be better for Event to contain a ICollection<Dog>? Dog will then contain its result so you would be able to sort the dogs in order by event. Also Dog could contain an ICollection<event> as dogs can appear in multiple events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really a good idea to do many to many relationships like how you've done. [See here](https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/5688-orms-you-re-doing-it-wrong)

In order to get a proper many to many relationship, mapped in the proper way in the database, that doesn't have pitfalls, I would try it this way:

```
public class Dog {}
public class Event {}

public class Result {}

// This is a linking table between Dog and Results
public class DogResult
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int DogId {get;set;}
    public int ResultId {get;set;}
}

// This is a linking table between Events and Results
public class EventResult
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int EventId {get;set;}
    public int ResultId {get;set;}
}
```

When you now write your query you can do this:

```
using (var context = new DbContext())
{
   var dogs = context.Dogs();
   var dogResults = context.DogResults();
   var results = context.Results();

   var dogsAndResults = dogs.Join(
          dogResults,
          d => d.Id,
          r => r.DogId,
          (dog, dogResult) => new { dog, dogResult })
       .Join(
          results,
          a => a.dogResult.ResultId,
          r => r.Id,
          (anon, result) => new { anon.dog, result });
}
```

It is a bit nasty looking, but it will give you back a list of anonymous objects containing a `Dog` and its related `Result`. But obviously it would be better to do this in a stored proc:

```
using (var context = new DbContext())
{
    var results = context.Database.ExecuteStoreQuery<SomeResultDto>("SELECT * .... JOIN ... ");
}
```

This is cleaner, because you are using SQL.

This is a more complex way of dealing with it. But far more performant, especially if you understand fully how entity framework executes LINQ.

Obviously if you want to create these links:

```
using (var context = new DbContext()) 
{
    context.Dogs.AddRange(dogs); // dogs being a list of dog entities
    context.Results.AddRange(results); // events being a list of results entities

    context.DogResults.AddRange(dogResults); // a list of the links
}
```

It is completely up to you how you create these links. To turn this into a sproc as well, you want to create some custom User Defined Table Types and use them as a Table Value Parameter.

```
var dogResults = dogs.SelectMany( d => results.Select ( r => new DogResult { DogId = d.Id, ResultId = r.Id } ) );
```

That is a beast of a LINQ query and basically it gets every dog and links it to every result. Run it in LinqPad and `Dump` the values.

Comment: thank you very much, i´ll try to look into this and see if I can understand it. Thanks!

Comment: But you mean that I should leave my classes as is and simply add the two new classes? Dogresult and Eventresult? Or di I have to make other changes as well in my other three classes?

Comment: just add the two extra classes, leave the others as is! Apart from you need to remove the navigation properties.

Comment: Ok! The navigation-properties, are those the ones that has the word virtual in them? 2 ICollections and 2 "regular properties?"

Comment: yeah they are. These properties have virtual to instruct EF not to get their value until you ask for them. This can potentially lead to SELECT N + 1 situations. Which isn't ideal.

Answer (score 1):

I've only done this using the fluent method (when I was learning I found you can do everything in fluent, but not with annotations, so I've not looked into them), the following creates a many to many between my `Unit` entity and my `UnitService` entity:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Unit>()
            .HasMany<UnitService>(u => u.Services)
            .WithMany(us => us.Units);
```

This code is in the `protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method.

In your case `Event` is `Unit` and `Dog` is `UnitService`.

Oh ooops, you don't need that at all, your 'join' table is your results table, in my case I don't care about the join table so its all hidden.
Maybe something like:

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Result>()
               .HasMany<Event>(e => e.Results);
   modelBuilder.Entity<Result>()
               .HasMany<Dog>(d => d.Results);
```