# .NET Entity Framework - Code First Design For User has Service with Settings based on User

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, web-services

My .NET WebAPI project with Identity offers several services that (registered) users can consume. Access to the services is granted per user, so UserA may consume Service1, Service2 and Service3 while UserB may consume Service1, Service2, Service4 and Service5.

Every service has 0..n settings / configurations. The settings value used in the service depends also on the user.

Example:

We have users Alice, Bob, Eve (currently default ASP NET identity users) and the services "Random Number", "Search" and "Weather Forecast". Random number needs no settings, search needs the search engine to be used and weather forecast needs the temperature style (Celsius / Fahrenheit) and the forecast provider.

Alice may use all three services, with Google as search engine and weather forecast in Celsius from weather.com. Bob may only use the search service with Bing as backend. Eve may use the search with Google and the weather forecast in Fahrenheit from accuweather.

I'm stuck in designing the tables in the code first approach with EF. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, thanks for the hint. I'll pay attention to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Service
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class UserService
{
    [Key, Column(0)] // this creates a composite key
    public int ServiceId {get;set;}
    [Key, Column(1)] // this creates a composite key
    public string UserId {get;set;}
}
```

So this creates a many to many relationship between users and services that you provide. So you can add a user to a multiple services. Here are the Settings:

```
public class Settings
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int UserId {get;set;} // the user
    public int ServiceId {get;set;} // the service
}
```

So to clarify this is settings based on 1 setting per User per Service. You would have to make it a many to many if you wanted multiple settings per User per Service.

Hopefully this would be a good start.

As a point to note, I do not use relationships i.e. `public virtual Settings Settings {get;set;}`. I just join it from the database myself like below. I especially don't user relationships for many to many mappings, there is too much magic! [see one of my answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26729822/entity-framework-relationships/26730485#26730485). I advise you to never use lazy loading virtual properties for many to many relationships with EF.

In order to get the services I would do this:

```
using (var context = new DbContext())
{
    var usersWithServices = context.Users.GroupJoin(
        context.UserServices,
        u => u.Id,
        j => j.UserId,
        (user, @join) => new {
            user,
            @join
        }).Select(a => 
            a.join.GroupJoin(
                context.Services,
                j => j.ServiceId,
                s => s.Id,
                (@join, service) => new {
                    a.user,
                    @join,
                    service
                })).ToList();
}
```

Put this into LinqPad and it will run like a beaut, it is a beast though. It basically returns `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<>>` and in the inner most `IEnumerable` is an anoynonmous object which contains a `User`, `UserService`, `Service`. Or atleast from Linqpad that is what I can make out. Put it into VS and you'll know exactly what you're dealing with.