# Entity Framework 6 entity mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to write a simple CRUD on C#.

I am having troubles defining the relationships between these entities:

```
public class Movie
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; }  
    public Director Director { get; set; }
}

public class Director
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }     
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Movie> DirectedMovies { get; set; }
}
```

How do I make it so that one director can have multiple movies and one movie can have one director?

The `Movie` table has the `DirectorId` column but I cannot find a way to add a director to the movie from the frontend side.

In `MovieController`, I have this code:

```
public ActionResult performAddMovie(Movie movie) 
{
    try
    {
        ctx.Movies.Add(movie);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    catch(Exception ex) 
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Messaggio", ex.Message);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

This lets me add a new movie to the database, but I don't know how to add a director too.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Have a list of objects as a foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614828/have-a-list-of-objects-as-a-foreign-key)

Answer (score 1):

The `Director` is just another property. Presumably, before you pass a particular `Movie` object to `performAddMovie`, you're setting the title of the `Movie`.

If you've got the ID of `Director`, you can do:

```
var director = ctx.Directors.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == directorId);
movie.Director = director;

return performAddMovie(movie);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have add DirectorId property in Movie class

Answer (score 0):

Check this following code

```
Check this following code 

public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int DirectorId { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("DirectorId")] 
    public Director Director { get; set; }
 }

public class Director
{
    public int DirectorId { get; set; }     
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Movie> DirectedMovies { get; set; }
}
```